# Woocommerce: Delete Countries from Dropdown Menu at Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to delete all of the countries that are set by Woocommerce.
Can Someone tell me where I can see / modify the list of countries that are set by woocommerce? I've already looked at `class-c-countries.php` in woocommerce and I'm pretty sure that this method `public function get_countries()` gets the list of countries, but it seems like it gets them by using `woocommerce_countries` so I can't really edit it. And I can't seem to be able to access that list/file.

Here is the method:

```
 public function get_countries() {
    if ( empty( $this->countries ) ) {
        $this->countries = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_countries', include( WC()->plugin_path() . '/i18n/countries.php' ) );
        if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sort_countries', true ) ) {
            asort( $this->countries );
        }
    }
    return $this->countries;
}
```

I can post the whole `.php` file if needed, please let me know.
Thanks in advance for the help!

I don't really know much about `php` btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in your Woocommerce settings, no PHP needed. Set "Selling Location(s)" to "specific countries" and only select the ones you want to be displayed in checkout. Please see Woocommerce documentation:
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/